# How do I move my farm animals?

Tags: starbound

I bought and hatched some farm animals for my colony, but now as I expand I realized the roof of my house is perhaps not the best place to put my <del>cows</del> excuse me, Fluffalos. None of the tools I've tried to use so far have had any effect on them, however.

Is there any way I can pick them up and move them somewhere else?

Comment: I guess this kind of also answers whether or not I will be able to get my Fluffalo off of my ship ever.

Comment: @Reafexus I noticed enemies seem to damage farm animals (my Fluffalo flinched when a bird hit it), and if the wiki is to be believed they are also vulnerable to lava (the wiki can be outdated though). I personally would rather not having to kill my animals just to move them, since they are rather expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Just build a [Relocator](https://starbounder.org/Relocator) at an [Agricultural Station](https://starbounder.org/Agricultural_Station) (Stage 2 Foraging Table). You need

- 10 × Durasteel Bar
- 4 × AA Battery
- 2 × Silicon Board
- 6 × Copper Wire

Then you can pick up up to three small critters, fish, bugs, punchy and farm animals and place them somewhere else.

Comment: While this does answer the question perhaps you could add more information about the relocator and how it is used to further improve your answer.

Answer (score 8):

There is no direct way to do that, however due to the game giving you so many freedoms, you can use a little trick.

If you have it, you can simply use a [two-handed-staff which secondary ability sets up a Repulsion Zone](http://starbounder.org/Staffs). You should be able to use the repel shield to move all manner of things, including NPCs and Fluffalos to the location you want them to be.

Comment: This is a pretty neat trick! Unfortunately I think I've sold all my starves already, and there doesn't seem to be one available for crafting that has this special ability.

Comment: @PrivatePansy I frankly don't know of an alternative, nor how to easily get the staff.

Comment: you can get the staff using console commands which would technically be cheating but if there's no honest way to do this then it might be a viable workaround

Comment: Attraction zone also works

Comment: It's unfortunate that this trick doesn't put them into the teleporter and activate it :p

Comment: I think the Adaptive Crossbow's push/pull arrows will work also.

Answer (score 5):

Once you upgrade to I think the final agricultural table, you can build a relocator. The relocator sucks up passive creatures (like farm animals and the little lizards, squirrels, etc., running around, and then it beams them out anyplace you like by using the opposite button on the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have the staff like myself and only have a short distance to move them you can place a three tall barrier of any block to prevent them from going the wrong way. They also sleep at night so its a day thing and they only move around two to three tiles at time. Sometimes they will go the same direction twice so it will be a larger movement but they will go back the way they just came from 90% of the time. I have not tested with two tall tiles but I know three and four work fine. I am unsure if you can use a pet pod to pick them up or not but if you do a side quest from an npc there is a chance they will ask you to pick up some sort of wild mob. If you accept then you get a free capture pod then just deny the quest and try.

Hope that helps.
Kieran

Answer (score 0):

The most robust way to do this (as heartless as it sounds) is to kill your animals and buy new eggs. The other answers here won't work if you need to move your items from say your ship to a planet, which it seems a lot of people (including myself) do.

I've found the best way to do this is by using bombs, but any method should work, just be careful of destroying your own stuff.

Then just purchase them from the outpost and place wherever you like.

If you don't have any way of killing them or have enough money or if you don't want to spend so much money just to move it, I recommend using admin commands to acquire the money to do so.

`/admin` will give you admin rights. Then `/spawnitem diamond x` will give x amount of diamonds which you can sell for pixels. Then just purchase the eggs  that you need. Also `/spawnitem bomb 1` in order to get a bomb to kill them.