# How do I get a fluffalo off of my ship?

Tags: starbound

I put my Fluffalo down in my ship but I now have a colony to put it on instead. Is there anyway for me to collect it and move it? Killing it with lava appears to be my only option although that is a waste of Pixels.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/278896/how-do-i-move-my-farm-animals but I think it is sufficiently different and the current answers do not help me.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It's cuter than the default pets! It's so fluffy!

Comment: @Fluttershy As adorable as they might be, they do take up a lot of room... plus if i'm decorating my ship with skulls and coffins, a cute poofy Fluffalo throws off the ship's feng shui.

Comment: Also the pets on the ship get in the way of literally everything. Especially short activateable objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the Update 1.1 you can use the [Relocator](http://starbounder.org/Relocator) to pick up and place Animals on other Planets.

Answer (score 2):

Burn it with lava. It's one of those tasks that no one wants to do but you have to, 'cause you can't have a fluffalo running roughshod over your fancy ship.

Comment: Of course, the Relocater came out just one or two days after i burnt down my shipboard zoo :P

Comment: These whippersnappers and their new-fangled relocators. Why, back in my day, etc.